# HuggingFace TFRobertaModel detailed summary

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, TFRobertaModel
import tensorflow as tf

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
model = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
```

I want a detailed layer summary of this HuggingFace `TFRobertaModel()` so that I can visualize shapes, layers and customize if needed. However, when I did:
`model.summary()`, it just shows everything in a single layer. I tried digging into it's different attributes, but not able to get a detailed layer summary. Is it possible to do so?

```
Model: "tf_roberta_model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
roberta (TFRobertaMainLayer) multiple                  124645632 
=================================================================
Total params: 124,645,632
Trainable params: 124,645,632
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Also, there is a related [question](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/tensorflow-model-summary-doesnt-show-detail-of-tfbertmodel/799) in HuggingFace forum which hasn't been answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a model summary, but you can print the layers like this:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, TFRobertaModel
import tensorflow as tf

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
model = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained("roberta-base")

def print_layers(l, model):
  for idx, s in enumerate(l.submodules):
    if s.submodules:
      print_layers(s, model)
    print(s)

TFRobertaMainLayer = model.layers[0]   
print_layers(TFRobertaMainLayer, model)
```

You could also use `s.weights` to get the weights of each layer.

Comment: Thank you! This gave me a way to explore and change the layer options and weights easily.